# http headers not showing (sent with postman)

Tags: php

I have a simple code in php to test my headers:

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers() ;
echo var_dump($headers);
?>
```

I'm sending a simple get request with Postman (a google crome extention for immitating a client) and putting a auth header, but the added header is not printing out. I also tried putting in other types of headers like time, and nothing changed. Is this a problem with postman or my code/understanding of headers?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after extensive searching this was my solution:

In my .htaccess file I added

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

So this my full Rewrite block in my .htaccess file now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule v1/(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Source: http://jhtechservices.com/2014/06/passing-authorization-header-to-php-program-when-fastcgi-php-being-used/